# Getting dimensions of an UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I would like to determine the dimensions (especially number of lines) of a certain text string if placed in an UITextView with the dimensions 200 x 460 pixels, font Courier.

I tried to call the following method in order to get an integer which I can then display. However, it won't work (xCode tells me that I have incompatible types in the initialization):

```
NSString *temp2String;
    temp2String = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[textView text]];

    int strSize = [temp2String sizeWithFont:@"Courier" constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(200, 10000)
                   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    NSString *temp2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Size of string: %d", strSize];
    textViewSize.text = temp2;
    [temp2 release];
```

I am a beginner and I posted a similar question earlier today, but I still can't figure out how to get CGSize to work and give me the answer I need. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Note that `sizeWithFont:` takes a UIFont, not a string naming the font. You can use `[UIFont fontWithName:... size:...]` to try to instantiate a font, or `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:...]` to instantiate the default font. See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIFont) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGSize is a structure (from CGGeometry.h):

```
struct CGSize {
  CGFloat width;
  CGFloat height;
};
```

Hence all you need to do is to fetch it and display whatever dimension you need to;

```
CGSize strSize = [temp2String sizeWithFont:@"Courier" constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(200, 10000)
                   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

Following your example (note the dimensions are given in float-values):

```
NSString *temp2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Width of string: %f", strSize.width];
textViewSize.text = temp2;
[temp2 release];
```

Answer (score 1):

`CGSize` is a struct. It contains two floats, named 'height' and 'width'.

```
CGSize strSize = [temp2String sizeWithFont:@"Courier" constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(200, 10000)
                   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
NSLog(@"Height %f, width %f", strSize.height, strSize.width);
```

Comment: Thanks! and sorry for this beginner's question. Thanks you!

Comment: No worries, we all started sometime.